# Get Status via status ID

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-opengraph

I am using Open Graph and Access token of a user.
I am able to echo status id of a user via this code 'echo $status[id];'and name via `<?php echo $userData['name']; ?>`
This code returns last status id of a user.
I want to print the status as itself using this id or I want to echo actual status using this id i got from `' .

Comment: If you print the complete $userData array, is the status itself listed somewehere? Use `print_r($userData);`

Comment: @edwardmp when I print $userData['name']; it display name when I type $userData['id']; it display id of the user but when I echo $userData it only print the word "Array"

Comment: Why do you think I asked you to use `print_r` not echo.. Please start reading

Comment: yes i can see the array but i cant see the status itself

Comment: Read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/

Comment: I got the status via print_r($status);? now I want to ask can I retrieve last 5 status like feed?